# Assign value to a column with while and cumsum conditions

Tags: python, pandas, while-loop, cumsum

I have tried the solution but it didn't work for me. I'm going to explain the complete problem. What I have to do is an optimization to assign clients to commercial employees. The columns will be "center" (commercial department), "client" (nº of client), "user" (the employee responsable of this client **if a client has no user, that means it's a new client**), "value" (its a value assigned to each client) and "assigned_user", that's a column created by me where should be the final employee assigned to this client according to the criterion of optimization. My initial df is:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
"center": ['0060','0060','0060','0060','0060','0060','0060','0060','0060','0060','0070','0070','0070','0070','0070','0070','0070','0070','0080','0080','0080','0080','0080','0080','0080','0080','0080','0080','0080','0080','0080'],
"client": ['C00001','C00002','C00003','C00004','C00005','C00006','C00007','C00008','C00009','C00010','C00011','C00012','C00013','C00014','C00015','C00016','C00017','C00018','C00019','C00020','C00021','C00022','C00023','C00024','C00025','C00026','C00027','C00028','C00029','C00030','C00031'],
"user": ['A','A','A','A','A','B','B','B','NaN','NaN','C','C','C','C','C','D','D','D','E','E','E','E','E','F','F','F','G','G','NaN','NaN','NaN'],
"value": [5,5,3,5,2,5,2,2,2,3,5,4,4,1,1,3,3,3,5,3,2,2,5,5,2,2,5,3,1,2,3], 
"assigned_user": ['NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN','NaN']
})
```

What I need is to make an optimal distribution according to the value of the clients for each employee and center. For example, for center (or department) 0060, I have two employees (A & B) and a total value of clients = 34, so each user should have clients with a total value of 17 in the column assigned_user. In this center, according to column user, A has clients with a total value of 20 and B has 9. I have to reassign the clients trying to keep maximum possible of clients in each employees, for A, it needs to loose a client with a value of 3, and for B, it needs to keep his initial clients, get the clients not assigned (NaN in column "user") and get the client that A has to loose.

For center 0080, we have 3 employees (E, F & G) and a total client value of 40. Each employee should have clients with total value around 13.3 (doesn't have to be exactly, just closest possible value). In this case according to column "user", E has a total client value of 17, F has 9 and and G has 8. There is also 3 clients whithout employee and a total value of 6. In this case, E should loose clients with a value of 3 or 4, and assign this clients (and the clients without assigned employee) to employees F & G, and as always, keeping the employees that F and G have already assigned and trying F and G has a total value closest possible to 13,3 in column "assigned_user" (they both could have 13 or one could have 14 and the other 12, it doesn't care).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry for my explication. What I need is to complete column "assigned_user" with users in column "user", but each user of column "assigned_user" can't have a total value > 10. This is part of a bigger dataset, I just tried to simplify. In case of "assigned_user" = A, it already has a value of 10 (two first rows of column value). What I need for users B and C is to complete NaNs of column "assigned_user" with users B or C until they had a value of 10 (as user A)

Comment: should the groups be consecutive? for instance if we swap the second and third NaN value, what should happen?

Comment: They don't have to be consecutive, there is only three conditions: 1º- each group of users (A,B or C) must have aproximately the same value (A could be 10, B=9 and C=11). 2º- Values A, B or C in column "assigned_user" must keep the value already have. 3º- In output dataset cannot have a NaN value in "assigned_user" column because all rows must have an assigned user.

Comment: Then this looks like a [Subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), which NP-complete (difficult to solve efficiently)

Comment: Thank for your help @mozway, but it didn't worked. I have change the description of the problem and tried to give a complete description.

Answer (score 1):

First of all this is not a optimized algo to solve this problem because I am not completely dependent on broadcasting concepts provided by numpy.

And, for sake of easy typing I am using only useful column required for solution of our case these are `value` and `asigned_user`.

**ALGORITHM :**

1. Using `np.cumsum` we calculate cumulative sum of `value` column
2. Then using module broadcasted operation on above result give use index number at which remender is zero which helps us in extracting no of `repeatitive occurrence`
3. Finally using cummlative difference we get no of occurance for each char.

**IMPLEMENTATION :**

```
from operator import index
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "value": [5, 5, 2, 3, 2, 3, 5, 5],
    "asigned_user":['A', 'A', 'B', 'B', np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan]
})

index = list(df.value[df.value.cumsum()%10 == 0].index + 1)
final_index = [index[0]]
final_index.extend(np.diff(index))

map_ = [j*i for i,j in zip(("A", "B", "C"), final_index)]
map_final = ''.join(map_)
df['assigned_user'] = list(map_final)

print(df)
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
   value asigned_user
0      5            A
1      5            A
2      2            B
3      3            B
4      2            B
5      3            B
6      5            C
7      5            C
```

Comment: Thank for your help @Martiancodeer, but it didn't worked. I have change the description of the problem and tried to give a complete description.